# Make navbar collapse menu appear on all screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

I have a question concerning bootstrap navbar. I want the collapse menu that appears on mobile, to also appear on larger devices. Since the code is rather large, I will have to share the codepen:

```
code link http://codepen.io/diazabdulm/pen/KMaREN
```

http://codepen.io/diazabdulm/pen/KMaREN

Comment: It is there you just can't see it. Add `navbar-default` as an example. `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-ct-primary" role="navigation-demo">`  [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) and you also need `jquery` and `bootstrapjs` for this to work.

Comment: Thanks vanburen! Solved it.